# row insertion in table not as should be

Tags: database, row, sql-insert, hsqldb

I have a DB table :

```
CREATE CACHED TABLE LOGIN(ROWNO INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS 
IDENTITY(START WITH 1,INCREMENT BY 1),USERID VARBINARY(128) PRIMARY 
KEY,LOGINA VARBINARY(128));
```

And a insert query :

```
prepareStatement = conn.prepareStatement(" INSERT INTO LOGIN 
(USERID,LOGINA) VALUES(?,?)”)
preparedStatement.setBytes(1,someBytes);
preparedStatement.setBytes(2,someOtherBytes);

preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

The table rows insertion is ***strange*** :

```
     RowNo   UserID   LoginA
 1     3     data3    data3
 2     2     data2    data2
 3     1     data1    data1
```

when a button clicked, a one new row inserted ..As you see RowNo 1 should be on top of the list rather than the last cuz it was the first inserted...each new inserted row comes at the top of the table ...any idea why and how to solve ?

Answer (score 0):

ok I found the reason ; basically I wanted the UserID to be a Primary Key to use as Foreign Key in other table ; here is the options :

1- RowNo not primary key ,UserID Primary Key : you get the strange table rows .

2- RowNo not primary key, UserId Unique : you get strange table rows  .

3- RowNo Primary Key , UserID Unique ....this will give you the correct table with rows numbers start with 1 downward. And since Unique key column can be used as Foreign Key, then all things good :)

Answer (score 0):

In a relational database, you should not expect the rows to be returned in a particular order without adding an ORDER BY clause to a SELECT statement. Your results are ordered on the PK column because HSQLDB uses the primary key index to return the results in this case. When there is an ORDER BY, it is guaranteed the rows are ordered regardless of the database software used, or the actual SELECT statement.

Comment: @fredit ...but the issue in my case wasn't the SELECT ...it was the INSERT , the strange arrangement of rows happens upon using the INSERT ...even without using a SELECT to query the table later on. And yes it seems HSQLDB depends on the Primary Key for INSERT as well .

Comment: @fredit...unless your meaning is that upon using the SELECT when showing the data, I use the ORDERBY ...well, I will check.

Comment: @fredit ..and due to a special requirement in the program.. my way is more convenient . I appreciate to you.